# Some buttons are too big?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, system-monitor

I don't know how this happened, but certain buttons are showing as gigantic and it looks weird. In Files, the directory buttons like home, forward, back etc are huge. Same thing with System Monitor, and it's messing up the position of the window buttons (which are the right size.) Most everything else is OK though, its just random buttons in places like that. Help?

[image]

[image]

---

So since I found out what the problem is, I changed the question and put it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/529848/icon-theme-got-messed-up
Any more help?

Comment: Changed theme recently? Or changed nautilus settings?

Answer (score 1):

Well, im not sure, are you experiencing from earlier u installed the OS? 
What I'd do is to refresh icon theme with ubuntu tweak or such app. just open it and select a new theme, then came back to the original.
You can also try this if the problem doesn't go beyond nautilus: Open synaptic pakage manager and totally unninstall and wipe all configuration files, then reboot and reinstall nautilus.

I hope this works for you

Comment: hmm, yeah it seems to be a problem with the icon theme. It has 2 variants and they are both glitchy like that, don't know why. thanks!